# To Run an MSI with no user logged on and default folder in Users\*\Appdata\Roaming

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a MSI that creates it's default folder in Users*\Appdata\Roaming but the machines on which we have to execute the msi are all newly built. There are no users logged on. Is there an VBS or any suggestion that can execute this.

Answer (score 1):

You might not realize it, but your question is pretty broad.  There's an abundance of methods you could use to achieve this result.  The easiest would likely be to scrape the host fqdn's, iterate over the list, and use powershell to invoke-command an install action.

A preferred method would be to use some sort of configuration management.  Be it Chef, Ansible, Puppet, etc.  Though this requires some implementation and architecture which will necessitate some planning.

A package manager would likely be helpful too, chocolatey, nuget, etc.